# Как получить value из input?

Tags: jquery

Нужно получить значение заполненного поля:

```
var mailData = $("input.for-mail").val();
```

Если **value** заполнен вручную изначально, то всё окей. Но заполненный пользователем **value** получить не удаётся (судя по инспектору, введённое вообще не записывается в **value** почему-то).

Как получить введённые в input данные?

Comment: Скорее всего, ошибка не в этой строке.

Comment: Попробуйте в консоле набрать `$('.for-mail').val();`

Comment: Вот целиком:

var mailData = $("input.for-mail").val();
var mailUrl = "http://домен/?email=" + mailData + "&lcode=53856";
$(".button").click(function(){
 $("#rez").load(mailUrl);
});

Comment: @ilyaloser, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 8):

Проблема в том, что вы получаете переменную mailData один раз, при загрузке страницы, и там всегда находится значение по умолчанию. Перенесите получение значения текстового поля в обработчик события click.

Comment: Спасибо! :-)